# Ant.Design Tabs alignment

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, antd

I have made a basic Tabs component following this documentation [here](https://ant.design/components/tabs/).

This is my current output.
[image]

**Does anyone know the CSS to align ant-tabs-tab at the center?**

I can see that there are different position placement however there isn't a top-center option.

Current CSS:

```
  .ant-tabs-tab {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

The output from the above CSS. I would like to keep the same size as the first image but have it center aligned. Not sure if this is possible but I thought I'd check first.

[image]

Comment: flex grow 1 will do nothing as the parent of the tabs are not display flex, if they are then you  need to create a [mcve] demonstrating what you currently have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

```
.ant-tabs-nav-scroll {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: Edit Q]

Comment: Yes, perfect thank you. I was targeting the wrong class!

Answer (score 8):

You have a property called centered in the Tabs component and all your TabPane will be centered.

```
<Tabs centered>
```